# Making fcitx work under Lubuntu 21.10

Tags: lubuntu, input-language, fcitx

Following up on [Making fcitx work under Lubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177056/)

I've got all the `fcitx` packages I believe:

```
 fcitx_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-bin_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-config-common_0.4.10-3
 fcitx-config-gtk_0.4.10-3
 fcitx-data_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-frontend-all_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-frontend-gtk2_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-frontend-gtk3_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-frontend-qt5:amd64_1.2.5-1ubuntu2
 fcitx-googlepinyin:amd64_0.1.6-4build1
 fcitx-module-dbus_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-module-kimpanel_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-module-lua_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-module-x11_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-modules_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx-ui-classic_1:4.2.9.8-3
 fcitx5-module-quickphrase-editor:amd64_1.2.5-1ubuntu2
 libfcitx-config4:amd64_1:4.2.9.8-3
 libfcitx-core0:amd64_1:4.2.9.8-3
 libfcitx-gclient1:amd64_1:4.2.9.8-3
 libfcitx-qt5-1:amd64_1.2.5-1ubuntu2
 libfcitx-qt5-data_1.2.5-1ubuntu2
 libfcitx-utils0:amd64_1:4.2.9.8-3
```

But my fcitx config is still showing empty methods:

[image]

I've tried both `fcitx-config-gtk3` and `fcitx-configtool`. Both showing empty methods.

Consequently using hot key trying to invoke/trigger `fcitx` has no effect at all.

Anybody can help?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

Comment: Did you look in the manual?  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/search.html?q=fcitx&check_keywords=yes&area=default  as the manual clearly states "*First you must launch Fcitx to have it open in the system tray. To have Fcitx automatically start see Chapter 3.2.13.*"

Comment: @guiverc: That documentation is rather poor. Actually chapter 3.2.13 doesn't mention anything about fcitx, and it fails to point at the obvious tool on Lubuntu which I mentioned i my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to launch the fcitx daemon and configure your system to use fcitx.

- Open *Input Method Configuration*
- Select fcitx as the user configuration
- Reboot

Now you should see a fcitx icon and be able to add input methods to your liking.

Comment: For some reason my menu is screwed up and I can't find the configuration tool.  Can you tell me the command-line name?

Comment: @YanKingYin: Try: `fcitx-config-gtk3`